# ¿Qué significa {0} en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo un pregunta:

Que significa esto `{0}`, tengo entendido que `[0]` = recorre el array en la posición 0, pero `{0}`, ¿Para que sirve?, ¿Qué es lo que hace? y el `formant` también ¿Para que sirve?

Por ejemplo:

```
print("Curso {0} selecionado.".format(curso))
```

Resultado:

> Curso biología seleccionado

Como resultado me da esto , estaba viendo un video y no entendí porque puso `{0}`.

Gracias.

Answer (score 5):

Se usa para asignar un valor a un String, se asigna la variable dentro de una nueva cadena usando [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) para asignarle el valor, en este caso del de la variable `curso`, el 0 indica el primer argumento de format :

```
curso = "Biología"
print("Curso {0} selecionado.".format(curso))
```

pero en este caso como solo tienes un valor puedes usar únicamente `{}`

```
print("Curso {} selecionado.".format(curso))
```

salida:

```
Curso Biología selecionado.
```

Si tuvieras más de 1 argumento que envias a [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) , este es un ejemplo:

```
curso = "Biología"
dia = "Martes"
print("Curso {0} selecionado, día {1}.".format(curso, dia))
```

salida:

```
Curso Biología selecionado, día Martes.
```

Answer (score 4):

Según la documentación de [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.format)

> Realiza una operación de formateo. La cadena de caracteres sobre la
> que se está ejecutando este método puede contener texto literal y
> también **marcas de reemplazo de texto definidas mediante llaves {}**.
> Cada sección a reemplazar contiene o bien un índice numérico que hace
> referencia a un parámetro por posición, o el nombre de un parámetro
> por nombre. retorna una copia de la cadena donde se han sustituido las
> marcas de reemplazo por los valores correspondientes pasados como
> parámetros.

Es decir, son marcas de reemplazo de texto, dónde, por ejemplo en tú código `print("Curso {0} selecionado.".format(curso))`, el `{0}` le indica a `format` que debe reemplazar ese lugar con el valor del primer parámetro recibido, es decir, el valor de la variable `curso`.

Por supuesto no está limitado a un único parámetro, ni a datos tipo cadena:

```
"La suma de {0} y {1} es {2}".format(1, 2, 1 + 2)
```

Y asimismo, tiene varias opciones para [formateo](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) de estos reemplazos